# How would handle l10n application with Zend Framework?

Tags: php, zend-framework, localization, internationalization

Hi let's say I've the following application:

- Not localized
- One database language agnostic

I need to make this application l10n and i18n.

Each websites will be available through one domain (domain.co.uk, domain.fr, domain.it or maybe from a subdomain fr.domain.com, en.domain.com, it.domain.com which is more relevant to the language than the localization).

For example, **how will you do with the database ?**

One database with a locale information on each entity?

like id, article_title, article_body, article_locale? or separate database ?

- domain_fr
- domain_en
- etc.

**How will you deploy application ?**

- One per vhost?
- The same pointing everywhere, but localized on bootstrap? Maybe choosing the db would be tricky here.

**What about the backwards compatibility with the current application?**

My thoughts:

- Using differents vhosts/server per languages
- Using the application.ini to define the local
- Using the application.ini to choose the db to use

Since the application is localized with different content, I don't need to be able to switch language within it, so I can hardcode the locale in the configs.

The only bad point I can see here is the db evolution, since it's several database if I need to add a column I'll have to do it everywhere. So maybe a central database with a locale option where needed would be better but will probably require more work.

What are feedbacks? It's a decisive decision here and I want to take the right way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use different think to goal your requirements:

1. Because you use different vHost for each language, you can set the Local in an environement variable. **OR** using a specific route based on the hostname.
2. After having the locale, you need to specify the i18n, using Zend_Translate
3. Next I recommand you to create an extra field in DB to select the language (the most simple solution) **OR** have different database select by Langugage in the Bootstrap (less easy to maintain)

For table example `pagecontent`, you'll have:

- PageID (primary)
- Language (primary)
- Title
- Resume
- Content

With one tuple by "content and language".

Comment: Thanks for your answer, what are your though of handling the locale information within the model? Is it better to explicitly request it in get*() or find*() methods? Or directly use the Zend_Locale::getLocale() method inside the model?

Comment: `Zend_Locale::getLocale()` is better, because you don't need to make changes in your application unless in your models.